# Send multiple POST requests using a single curl command

Tags: curl

Curl allows multiple GET requests to be made with a single command using `{a,b}` as different variable inputs, e.g.

```
curl 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client={firefox,chrome}&q=potato&hl=en' -o '#1_tst'
```

Is there a way to do the same for POST requests? I've attempted

```
curl 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search' -X POST --data 'client={chrome,firefox}&q=potato&hl=en' -o '#1_tst'
```

which results in a single file named `"#1_tst"` being written out. (This specific example request will fail no matter what, but l would like for two separate requests to be made).

Comment: Is there a reason you want it to be a single curl command (which requires curl itself to have the support, if taken literally), as opposed to a loop where bash calls curl multiple times? The loop approach can be made terse, if that's your concern; but as this is originally posed it's a curl question only and not a bash question at all, since "a single curl command" can't take advantage of any of bash's looping or expansion features.

Comment: (In `curl 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client={firefox,chrome}&q=potato&hl=en' -o '#1_tst'`, if it literally works exactly the way described, it _is_ `curl` and not bash doing the looping; but any answer to how to do that in other context would need to be found in the curl documentation alone -- and you'll note that the curl documentation describes the syntax _only_ in the URL-format section).

Comment: Looking at man page, it seems curl has `{a,b}` syntax only for URL, not for --data.

Comment: The reason to put it into a single curl rather than a for loop, which is the workaround l've been doing, is to recycle the TCP session. Depending on what l'm trying to do, the handshake can be the largest part of the time spent on the process.

That said, `{a,b}` being the wrong syntax for stringing POSTs together doesn't itself imply that there's no way to string POSTs together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl's [`--next` option](https://manpath.be/f37/1/curl#L2382) for this.

Example:

```
curl --url 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search' \
     --data 'client=chrome&q=potato&hl=en' -o 'chrome_tst' \
     --next \
     --url 'https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search' \
     --data 'client=firefox&q=potato&hl=en' -o 'firefox_tst'
```

Alternatively, you can parametrize your command line in your shell and supply it via [`--config`](http://manpath.be/f37/1/curl#L475):

```
curl --config <(for i in chrome firefox; do
    printf '--url https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search\n';
    printf '--data client='$i'&q=potato&hl=en\n-o '$i'_tst\n'; done)
```

---

Note that I have left out `-X POST` because `--data` already sets the [right method](https://manpath.be/f37/1/curl#L3587):

> Normally  you  do  not need this option. All sorts of GET, HEAD,
> POST and PUT requests are rather invoked by using dedicated com‐
> mand line options.
>
> This  option  only  changes the actual word used in the HTTP re‐
> quest, it does not alter the way curl behaves. So for example if
> you  want  to make a proper HEAD request, using -X HEAD will not
> suffice. You need to use the --head option.

Comment: incredibly cursory testing suggests that this recycles the tcp and tls sessions if the server host is the same. Thanks a lot!